# Can we say "the pot is leaking" or "the pot leaks" when the pot is empty?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-usage

[In the dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/leak)

> leak: 1 [intransitive, transitive] if a container, pipe, roof etc
> leaks, or if it leaks gas, liquid etc, there is a small hole or crack
> in it that lets gas or liquid flow through
>
> The roof is leaking.
> A tanker is leaking oil off the coast of Scotland

I am not sure when we can use the verb "leak"

Can we use the verb "leak" when there is not water present in the container?

Can we say "**the pot is leaking**" or "**the pot leaks**" when the pot is empty?

Comment: I might have preferred "The pot is leaky". But since the question was about usage of the verb, rather than how to describe a pot with cracks in it, that alternative is not directly relevant. And it might also be my non-nativeness showing through. In my native language, the verb is used to describe actual liquid pouring out, while the adjective is used to describe the state of disrepair.

Comment: @Arthur I think it's very relevant. "The pot leaks" and "the pot is leaky" are the two most correct options to me.

Comment: I've had plenty of things that leaked -- tires, buckets, travel mugs, pens, but never a pot. How  and where does a pot leak?

Comment: A pot leaks if liquid emerges from an unintentional hole or crack. A deliberate hole, such as one in a flower pot, would be described as draining rather than leaking. Pots are often made of brittle stuff like porcelain, cast iron, brass, etc. Cracks or holes may occur due to temperature changes, allowing liquid to leak out. Modern kitchenware tends to be aluminum, and cooking over fires is less common, but leaky ceramics such as teapots, coffee pots, etc. are still commonplace. In the past an entire profession existed to repair such leaks, the tinker.

Comment: "the pot is leaking" means it is happening **right now**, so that would not be correct.  "the pot leaks" is correct, or slightly better "the pot is leaky".

Comment: First year English: simple present versus present progressive. He plays tennis. He is playing tennis.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To describe something that has a hole or crack in it enough to allow the contents to leak, we normally use *present simple*, so "*the pot leaks*" is correct and the most natural way to describe it. At the pragmatics level, it means, "When the pot has fluid in it, the fluid leaks out".

The *present continuous* generally refers to actions happening *right now*, or to *a temporary situation*. "*The pot is leaking*" will usually mean that the pot is leaking *right now*, so it cannot be empty. And if it refers to an empty pot, it means "the pot leaks, and this situation is temporary", so it implies that the issue will soon be solved, perhaps by the pot being mended or replaced.

Comment: Excellent final point about the (slightly unusual) context where we *could* (but don't *have* to) use present continuous to refer to a leaky vessel that's currently empty. Not everyone would think of that (well, ***I*** didn't, anyway! :)

Comment: Such a use of present continuous is understandable, but it seems marginal to me. In linguistics terms, we say that the simple present can be used to indicate *potential aspect*. "The pot leaks" would be more explicitly stated as "the pot can leak", but that sounds unnatural... I think because verbs using the "can" modal (in active mode) should normally have a subject that is actually agentive.

Comment: I think it’s worth mentioning that a very natural way to convey the status of a leaky pot is to say “the pot has a leak”.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you would say to a plumber, "that radiator is leaking". Right now, it's not emitting water, because you turned both the valves to off.

Comment: @nigel222: No, I probably *wouldn't* use the continuous there! Nor would most native speakers, I think. Assuming I'd been able to shut both valves some time ago (perhaps days, weeks, or *months* earlier) so there was no actual water or damp presenting an ongoing problem, I'd be far more likely to say *This is the radiator that leaks.* My comment was simply made by way of recognizing that *some* speakers in *some* closely-related contexts might use the continuous for a fault that still exists even though it's not *currently* "going wrong".

Comment: @FumbleFingers well, I would. Are you from the UK like I am? This may be one of the subtle differences between USA, Canadian, Irish, Aussie and Kiwi versions.

Comment: @nigel222: I'd be *very* surprised if such a trivial usage difference could be meaningfully mapped on to geographical or socioeconomic linguistic communities / dialects. But who knows? Personally, I'd rarely if ever notice any difference between *This is the radiator that **leaks / is leaking / was leaking / leaked / has been leaking / ...*** IF the fault had been temporarily resolved before the plumber came. Such differences as exist between the communities you refer to mostly involve things that are ***often*** said in specific contexts. But this isn't a common context.

Answer (score 11):

"The pot leaks" is fine, as it is describing what the pot has the capability to ever do (specifically the pot has the ability "to leak"). This is even if it doesn't necessarily have the capability to *right now* (for example if there's no water in it). *(As [gotube's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/343441/9977) describes, this is the present simple.)*

"The pot is leaking" would imply that it is currently performing the action ("leaking"), which it can't do if it's empty. *(As [gotube's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/343441/9977) describes, this is the present continuous.)*

As far as actual description of a pot that's unable to hold it's water, another option as well is "the pot is leaky" (and is the one I'd probably use in day to day conversation).

Comment: The last paragraph is what I was thinking. And maybe a non-native speaker misheard it as "is leaking".

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but as a native English speaker one might say something that's leaky "is leaking" if it regularly receives water, like a gutter or a pipe.

As others have said, though, "the pot leaks/is leaky" is a more natural description for a pot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Another option I haven't seen mentioned is:

> the pot has a leak

This is what I instinctively reached for as a native speaker. A bit more verbose than "the pot's leaky", but it's another option.

Answer (score 0):

I could certainly say "the pot is leaking" for a pot that is currently empty if that pot keeps leaking whenever someone tries to keep a liquid in it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).